# Ignore sentry timeout in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, cypress, sentry

I have a self-hosted sentry on a low config server, therefore unfortunately sometimes the server doesn't respond for reasons, then sentry init requests timeouts, as a result,
sadly my next.js project doesn't build, also cypress test failed.

My question is how to ignore that sentry error on build time or ignore it in cypress?